# Firebase Cloud Functions - slow response when querying Firestore

Tags: firebase, express, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple Cloud Function in Firebase that takes JSON in an http POST and saves it to a Firestore collection. It's allocated 512MB memory.

The performance of this cloud function is very poor. If executed continuously, the round trip varies from 200-600ms and if executed infrequently (every 5-10 mins) it can take 4-10 seconds. I understand the cold start problem but on AWS I've never seen a cold start this slow, nor this frequent.

My code is below - I'd appreciate any insight into how to speed up performance.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// CORS Express middleware to enable CORS Requests.
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({ origin: true }))

app.post('/submitResponse', (req, res) => {
  console.log('/submitResponse');

  if (!req.body.info)
    res.status(422).send()

  const payload = req.body.info;
  console.log(payload);

  const responses = db.collection("responses")

  responses.add({
    payload: payload,
    timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  }).then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Response written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(docRef.id))
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
  });
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Bear in mind that both Cloud Functions and Cloud Firestore are both in beta and provide no guarantees for performance.  I'm sure if you compare performance with Realtime Database, you will see better numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the response Doug. So: (1) Would it be fair to say that this is normal performance for beta? (2) Is there anything I'm doing that is causing it to be abnormally slow? (3) Is it possible to influence cold starts?

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong here.  I've personally noticed that sometimes the turnaround is quick and other times not so much, so I can't really say what's "typical".  The Firebase team is actively working on this.

Comment: Ok thanks Doug - I appreciate your fast feedback!

Comment: @Doug Stevenson Firestore is out of beta, have their been improvements to this?

Comment: I've built a small game which uses cloud functions to perform transformation on users' data but the turnaround time is abysmal. It takes the "real-time" aspect away from my game.

Comment: not using Cloud Functions, but a Firestore/Firebase client (if only possible) should improve performance... and if it has to be Cloud Functions, one could try to log script start/progress/stop times, in order to see what takes the most time. it probably should be `JSON.stringify({docRefId: docRef.id})`.

Comment: I also experienced the same issue with my Firebase Cloud functions. But this is also documented in Cloud function website. Normally it will start after 10 seconds after the event happened. More over I am with free plan and I have not attached my payment method with Firebase account. I guess this would be the case for Free Plan.

Comment: it's been nine month since your test. I'm wondering if you could rerun  some code and see if you have the cold start issues ? Thanks for the article btw.

Answer (score 2):

To address [some of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198208/firebase-cloud-functions-slow-response-when-querying-firestore/53955164#comment87177528_49198208): at the time of writing [Cloud Firestore for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) is actually **still in beta**.

[image: Firestore is in Beta]

But Firestore is probably not the culprit in this case. The cold boot time of the cloud function is most likely overshadowing any database operation that you're having.

Cloud functions need time to spin up new instances whenever you have

1. Deployed new functions / first invocation
2. Instance has been recycled
3. Scaling up to handle load (request hitting new instance)

There's a [section about Cloud Function performance](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#performance) that mentions potential gains that you can make by minimizing your module dependencies.

> Because functions are stateless, the execution environment is often
>   initialized from scratch (during what is known as a cold start). When
>   a cold start occurs, the global context of the function is evaluated.
>
> If your functions import modules, the load time for those modules can
>   add to the invocation latency during a cold start. You can reduce this
>   latency, as well as the time needed to deploy your function, by
>   loading dependencies correctly and not loading dependencies your
>   function doesn't use.

Also check out the awesome [Cloud Performance Atlas video on the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOXrwFqR6kY) that mentions tips like:

- Reducing library dependencies
- Using more (most) popular versions of a package as it is more likely to already be cached
- Lazy loading modules that are not critical at boot

In case of library dependencies, the lowest hanging fruit is to get rid of dependencies that are either possible to implement yourself and/or only are using one or a few functions but requiring the whole library (I'm looking at you, lodash).